# Value become null for this in Promise callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am using the following code value of `this` become null when i call it inside the `then` function here is the code. Am i doing something wrong or it is like this or there is any work around to resolve this issue

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService }         from '../services/auth.service';
import { WebAPISettings }         from '../services/webapisettings.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  //_ngWEBAPISettings: WebAPISettings;
  //_authService: AuthService;

  constructor(private http: Http, private ngWEBAPISettings: WebAPISettings, private authService: AuthService) {
    //this._ngWEBAPISettings = ngWEBAPISettings;
    //this._authService = authService;
  }

  public login(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {

    let data = "grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


    try {
      debugger;
      return this.http.post(this.ngWEBAPISettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "token", data, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(function (res: Response) {
          debugger;
          let body = res.json();
          //let _authService: AuthService = new AuthService();

          this.authService.fillAuthDataFromLogin(body);
          //this.router.navigate(['/Home']);
          return body.data || {};
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);

    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

    }

  }


  private extractData() {

  }
  private handleError(error: any) {
    debugger;
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }


}
```

and i am debugging it in the chrome here is the screenshot please help me in fixing it.

[image]

after using the arrow function same thing check the screen shot

[image]

**one thing to mention i am using Angular2 RC4.**

Comment: Arrow functions : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an arrow function to be able to use the lexical this:

```
return this.http.post(this.ngWEBAPISettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "token", data, options)
    .toPromise()
    .then((res: Response) => { // <-----
      (...)
    });
```

This way, `this` will correspond to the instance of the `LoginService` service.

See this doc for more details:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: check last screenshot in the question no luck :(

Comment: That is an issue with dev tools.. you will get the correct value if you log it to the console. Reason being: Devtools shows you ts code but actually runs javascript code (es5). Therefore, this is still "null" instead of an instance of your class.

Comment: Not so obvious! I'm not sure to understand the reason ;-)

Comment: thanks for the help you guys are right it was showing null in dev tools